# Still necessary to apply APPSEC-212 patch for 1.8.1 CE?

Tags: magento-1.8, ce-1.8.1.0, security, patches

If a 1.8.1 CE site has all of the necessary security patches made available after APPSEC-212, but does not have APPSEC-212, should it be considered safe, as long as it is "safe" per curl https://magento.com/security-patch-check/[site]/[admin-dir]?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes it should consider safe if you have Allow symlinks disabled in magento

Developer > Template Settings > Allow Symlinks  NO

APPSEC-212 - Addresses a security issue and CMS problems when using symlinks

Comment: Thank you, I was able to follow your instruction easily and found that symlinks are not allowed, so appsec-212 won't be necessary. Much appreciated!